# Bug in Netbeans IDE Dev 201802140002?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-platform

Here is the code that's expected to produce error:

```
public class App {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        tick();
    }

    public static void tick () {
        System.out.print("hi");
```

Note that the closing angled bracket of both, the method `tick()` and class `App` is missing. Although the IDE indicates this error while writing code, this compiles and runs just fine. It doesn't look like an issue with Java (or my OS) as doing `javac` in the command line surely does fail.

What's even funnier...the following code throws a Runtime exception after successfully executing `tick()`:

```
public class App {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        tick();

    public static void tick () {
        System.out.print("hello..");
```

Here I skipped closing bracket of `main` too.

I have installed the development version of Netbeans that has support for Java 9.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just running an old version of the class?

Comment: No...I updated the text to be printed in `tick()` multiple times and it prints the updated text.

Comment: Just checking :) I think that you might be better off reporting this as a bug: https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html.

Comment: I'm going to. Just to be sure enough...does anyone else find this bug? Is it a bug in other releases of the IDE too?

Comment: @AndyTurner In line with NetBeans recently moving from Oracle to Apache, NetBeans bugs are now reported on Apache's web site using Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-449?jql=project%20%3D%20NETBEANS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah...I see it now. At some point of time I checked the "Always run without asking" checkbox and since then my IDE is ignoring all the compile time errors without any warnings.

[image]

Sorry guys...my bad.

Comment: Ha! Obvious once you gave the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a comment more than an answer, but I wanted to include screen shots to show that I cannot reproduce either issue.]

An interesting problem. I just downloaded the most recent nightly build (NetBeans Dev 201803060002) and built your code using Oracle JDK 9.04.

Neither of your code examples would compile for me. For the first example the error for the final line was "*reached end of file while parsing System.out.print("hi");*". Here is a screen shot:

[image: reachedEOF]

For the second example, where you removed the closing bracker of main() the additional error reported was "*illegal start of expression public static void tick () {*":

[image: reachedEOF2]

I suggest that you try the following:

- Create a new project and new class "App2" to see if you can replicate the issue with that same version of NetBeans.
- If you cannot then review why App compiles and App2 does not.
- If you can replicate the problem then download the most recently nightly build to see if you can still replicate the problem (i.e. Invalid source code compiles cleanly). If you cannot then I don't think it is worth raising a bug report or spending further time on the matter.
- However, if you can replicate the problem then by all means raise a bug report. But I strongly recommend being able to replicate the failure before doing that. Otherwise you are likely to get a WORKSFORME response if the NetBeans team cannot replicate the issue.

One more thing: it would be helpful to update your OP with the stack trace for that RuntimeException, which you should also include in your bug report.